# Session override flag isn't working in Appium 1.22.3

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-java

I'm starting the appium server using java (AppiumDriverLocalService).
Post the execution the appium remote session is not closed, when I rerun the same suite appium is using the same port numbers which is causing the failure of the suite (Port already in use). I added the session override flag to overcome the issue, still I'm facing the same issue

Below are the logs:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
Fatal Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:4723
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
at doListen (node:net:1559:7)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)


org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: unexpected end of stream on Connection{127.0.0.1:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/127.0.0.1:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: ‘XXXXXXXXX’, ip: '192.168.0.5', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '11.0.10'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver

at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:338)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:90)
```

Comment: Hey! Are you really quitting your appium instance upon execution in your after methods, like `teardown()`? If not, please implement it and this should resolve your issue.

Comment: We are using teardown in afterSuite which sometimes skips to kill the service when we are performing the parallel execution.

Comment: Refactor your implementation to make sure in `teardown()` so that be whatever your execution status is, the `teardown()` should get executed always. This will resolve your current issue!